# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer when handling multiple kind of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am recieving either of these formats from an external service.

**#successCase:** if success/error this will be thrown with proper status code

```
{:sellerid=>2200, :status=>"success"}
```

**#failureCase:** for unexpected errors am recieving this kind of hash and this is causing errors

```
{:property=>"instance.seller_mobile", :message=>"does not meet maximum length of 10", :schema=>{:type=>"string", :required=>true, :minLength=>1, :maxLength=>10}, :instance=>"01234ssss56789", :stack=>"instance.seller_mobile does not meet maximum length of 10"}
```

This is what I do with the response and here is where error happens(I think)

```
`if response[:status] == 'success'` 
#doing something
elsif response[:status] == 'error'
#doing something
end
```

If its **#successCase:** response this works fine. But if its **#failureCase:** am getting error

> TypeError:
>          no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

I can see that its raising error here   `Failure/Error: if parsed_response[:status] == 'success'`

Could someone tell me how to fix this?

> PS: "I tried in console and it seems to be working right but rails throws error"

Comment: Do the hash for the failureCase have the `:status` key? and/or any `error`value?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma no..

Comment: Do you know the Ruby and Rails versions?

Comment: `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]` & `Rails 5.0.1`

Comment: This error happens frequently when what you believe to be a hash somehow ends up wrapped in an array. `[:status]` will then complain that `:status` can not be converted from Symbol to Integer, the only allowed argument type for `Array#[]`.

Comment: @MichaelKohl should be the case.. Any suggestions on how to deal with this.. Now what I think to do is catch `TypeError` and do everything there for failure case

Comment: Well either change your code to return what you expect or deal with getting an array. Using an exception for this seems unnecessary at best.

Comment: @MichaelKohl the request is from a 3rd party service so have no control over it. Their documententation is also bit vague.. I am doing this inside a background job and dont want it to keep it retrying during unexpected cases as I cant predict what format the response comes in... So i think exception is the way to go here..

Answer (score 0):

I have came across similar issue, you may try call `response.stringify_keys` after get response, and then use `response["status"] == 'success'` instead of `response[:status] == 'success'`

If you can touch the code in your external service. Before response result the you can call `to_json`, this will convert symbol key to string key.

```
# in rails console
> response = {status: 'success', sellerid: 2200}
=> {:status=>"success", :sellerid=>2200} #symbol key
> response = {"status" => 'success', "sellerid" => 2200}
=> {"status"=>"success", "sellerid"=>2200}          
> response.to_json
=> "{\"status\":\"success\",\"sellerid\":2200}"
```

After that just call `response["status"] == 'success'` in your side.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this is not the case. I use symbolize during parsing to prevent this. So `response[:status]` works.. But i think the issue is @MichaelKohl  mentioned in the comment.